# Why do we need to pass const shared pointer as reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

While I was reading an open-source code, I found the following where a shared pointer is passed to a function in two different ways.

`class A{A();};`

`typedef std::shared_ptr<A> A_Ptr;`

`void func1(A_Ptr a);`

`void func2( const A_Ptr& a);`

What is the reason to pass it as a reference when const is used? I understand the writer of the func2 does not expect the function to be able to change anything in a. But can't we just do this `const A_Ptr a`? Also, what are the reason we shouldn't pass it with `A_Ptr & a` in func1?

Occurance of the above in the code:

Git: https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/

[List of FramePtr in the code](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/search?q=FramePtr&unscoped_q=FramePtr)

[void FrameHandlerMono::setFirstFrame(const FramePtr& first_frame)](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/blob/d6161063b47f36ce78252ee4c4fedf3f6d8f2898/svo/src/frame_handler_mono.cpp#L295)

[void DepthFilter::addFrame(FramePtr frame)](https://github.com/uzh-rpg/rpg_svo/blob/d6161063b47f36ce78252ee4c4fedf3f6d8f2898/svo/src/depth_filter.cpp#L82)

Comment: who ever said we "need" to?  Regardless, if you're not taking ownership, you should be passing either references or raw pointers, not owning smart pointers.

Comment: Do you mean specifically for shared_ptr or do you want to know why you should use const references generally?

Comment: What's `boost`? Where is `std::shared_ptr` you tagged your question? Read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: All the usual reasons for pass-by-const-reference instead of pass-by-value or pass-by-pointer.

For `func2`, no copy constructor is invoked and less bytes are pushed/popped onto the stack.

Passing by const reference, as in the case of `func2` also allows you to pass in a temporary reference if it makes sense to do so:  ala : `func2(make_shared<Frame>())`

Comment: @MichaelMahn Thanks for the comment. I have added more details.

Comment: @selbie Thanks for the kind explanation. If there is a reason that we shouldn't pass it with pass-by-reference as `FramePtr & frame` in func1, what will it be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But can't we just do this `const FramePtr` frame?

Sure, we could, but then the copy constructor would be invoked, which is for larger types (anything larger than the built-in types) normally more expensive than passing by reference. This is nothing specific to `shared_ptr`. It should be generally your default to pass any objects by const reference if you don't need a copy and don't want to change them. Only built-in types like int, float, or char should be passed-by-value.

More interesting is why `func1` uses a copy. Most probable case is that he needs a copy anyway, because he wants to keep a reference in the class. I couldn't find the exact file you're refering to in the github repository you've posted. If it's still unclear please past the function body of func1 into the question.

Edit: Ah, I see. Looks like the reason he passes-by-value here, has more to do with thread-safety. Didn't read the whole but otherwise the `shared_ptr` might be deleted by the owning thread if he passed by const reference.

Here for examle func needs pass-by-value cause otherwise the pointer could be deleted by the main thread. Probably something like this but more complicated:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

struct S {
    S() {}
};

void
//This signature would be false
//func(std::shared_ptr<S> const& s)
func(std::shared_ptr<S> s)
{
    std::cout << s.use_count() << '\n';
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(2s);
    //use_count would be 0 here if we pass by reference
    std::cout << s.use_count() << '\n';
}



int
main(int argc, char**) {
    std::shared_ptr<S> s{std::make_shared<S>()};

    std::thread t{func, std::ref(s)};

    std::this_thread::sleep_for(1s);

    s.reset();

    t.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the kind explanation! pass-by-const-reference is clear now but the copy is still not clear. I have added more links to the part of the code where he used a copy.

Comment: Awesome! I didn't even think about the thread. Now I see how I should use shared_ptr. Thank you!